# How make accordion detail list with UI fabric react

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, typescript, office-ui-fabric-react

I start with UI Fabric react; I am developing a FAQ; I use for that a list; but the result is not good; I want to do something looks like an accordion, where we can see the question as a header and when we click on it or a checker the cheveron;  answer is displayed, but don't know how to do that with UI fabric,  here is my code

```
public render(): JSX.Element {


const { faqList: originalItems } = this.props;
const { items = [] } = this.state;
const resultCountText = items.length === originalItems.length ? '' : ` (${items.length} of ${originalItems.length} shown)`;
const { selectedItem } = this.state;

return (
<div >


<Label>FAQ </Label> 
<FocusZone direction={FocusZoneDirection.vertical}>
<Dropdown
label="Categories"
selectedKey={selectedItem ? selectedItem.key : undefined}
onChange={this._onChange}
placeholder="Selectionnez une catégorie"
options={this.state.categorieOption}
styles={{ dropdown: { width: 300 } }}
/>
<TextField label={'Filtre par question' + resultCountText} onChange={this._onFilterChanged} />
<List items={items} onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell}  />
</FocusZone>
</div>
);
}

private _onRenderCell(item: IExampleItem, index: number | undefined): JSX.Element {
return (

<div className={classNames.itemCell} data-is-focusable={true}>

<div className={classNames.itemContent}>
<div className={classNames.itemQuestion}>{item.Question}</div>
<div className={classNames.itemReponse}>{item.Reponse}</div>
<div className={classNames.itemIndex}>{`Langue :  ${item.Langue.Nom}`}</div>

</div>

</div>
);
}
```

this code give me this result 
[image]

i wish to do something like this 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Khadi,

I've been meaning to create an accordion control for SPFx web parts, so I took this opportunity to build one in response to your question -- I hope you won't mind.

Take a look at the sample at https://github.com/hugoabernier/AccordionWebPart

It creates an accordion which is designed to look like the accordion used in [Microsoft sites](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/home-use-program/frequently-asked-questions):

[image: Accordion Sample]

From the code sample above, it looks like you already know how to load and filter the questions from your source, so I didn't bother with loading the questions. Feel free to use your existing code for that part.

To use the control, just clone the repo and copy the `src\controls` folder onto your own solution, then, in your `_onRenderCell` method, call the control as follows:

```
private _onRenderCell(item: IFAQItem, index: number | undefined): JSX.Element {
    const { collapsed } = this.state;
    return (
      <Accordion title={item.Question}
        defaultCollapsed={ collapsed} className={styles.itemCell} key={index}>
        <div className={styles.itemContent}>
          <div className={styles.itemReponse}>{item.Reponse}</div>
          <div className={styles.itemIndex}>{`Langue :  ${item.Langue.Nom}`}</div>
        </div>
      </Accordion>
    );
  }
```

Make sure to include a reference to the control too in your imports:

```
import { Accordion } from '../../../controls/accordion';
```

You won't need the list component to render the accordion, so in your `render` method replace this:

```
<List items={items} onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell}  />
```

For this:

```
{items.map((item: IFAQItem, index: number) => {
    return this._onRenderCell(item, index);
})}
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: oh my god it's amazing hhh; thank you too much :D; it's exactly what i search

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad it helped. Let me know if you run into any issues. You should consider demoing your finished product so that others will learn from it!

Comment: i will add all on github later and share it here :D

Answer (score 0):

Hugo, thank you for Accordion version for Office UI fabric react. Although there is one problem with this code:

```js
this.state = {
    expanded: props.defaultCollapsed ? !props.defaultCollapsed : false
};
```

With this condition button won't be expanded by default when defaultCollapsed is explicitly set to false (expanded will be also false in this case). I changed it like this:

```js
this.state = {
    expanded: props.defaultCollapsed == null ? false : !props.defaultCollapsed
};
```

Condition "props.defaultCollapsed == null" will be true when defaultCollapsed = null or undefined. If defaultCollapsed is true or false - condition "props.defaultCollapsed == null" will be false and code will use "!props.defaultCollapsed" option. Will create PR.